# MySQL save error without error

Tags: mysql, error-handling

```php
<?php
include("pass.php"); 
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["login"])) {
    require_once ('connect.php');

    $not = $_POST["not"];

    if($not=="") {
        header("location:mybbeklents/admin/dashboard.php?cmd=1");
    } else {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO notlar (not,) VALUES ('$not')");
        header("location:mybbeklents/admin/dashboard.php?cmd=2");
    }
}
?>
```

This code doesn't work. They don't get saved into MySQL.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: According to the title: none?

Answer (score 1):

query should be

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO notlar (`not`) VALUES ('$not')");
```

Comment: please also change $not = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["not"]); to avoid bad people dropping your database

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO notlar (`not`) VALUES ('$not')")
OR die('MySQL error: '.mysql-error());
```

That echoes the error, if any occurs.

Note: Your query in insecure. Use [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PHP PDO**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or at least unescape your variables before passing them to the query.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$not = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["not"]);
```

and

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO notlar (not) VALUES ('$not')");
```

If this works, take your time and read a bit on sql injection and the outdated mysql extension. It is really easy to drop your database the way your code looks right now.
You can solve both issues in your code using PDO. you'll find more information on PDO here:
http://www.phptherightway.com/#security